# linux print last row of all columns of data with varying row numbers for columns

Tags: unix, awk, cut

I have a file with the format,

```
1  1.0  1   1.0   1   2.0   1    3.0
2  2.0  2   3.0             2 
3  2.0  3   4.0
4  6.0 
5  3.0
```

I want to print last row  of all column. In actual data, row and column numbers in the range of 100s.
I have tried with tail, awk, and cut commands, but didn't succeed.

Desired Output

```
5 3.0   3 4.0  1 2.0  1 3.0
```

Comment: What have you tried? note that the 2 in the 7th row can be easily considered in the 5th row by awk.

Comment: Can you clarify your file format? Is there deliberately no data for row 2? Also why doesn't row 4 appear?

Comment: @MannyD note that the desired output shows the last row of every column: `5` for first, `3.0` for 2nd, `3` for 3rd, `4.0` for 4th...

Comment: Is your data in a known fixed-width format? Are there specific field separators? Or is it just "whitespace"

Comment: Should the last "1" in the output actually be a "2"? If not, why not? Are your fields fixed-width or tab-separated or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing to do at this point would be just to write something in your scripting language of choice (Python, Ruby, etc.). The process might look something like this:

```
for line in file:
  columns = break_into_columns(line)
  #a good column format might be [[1, 1.0], [1, 1.0], [1, 2.0], [1, 3.0]]
  for i in len(columns):
    if columns[i][1]==None:
      if cache[i]!= None:    #so we only print the last item once
        print cache[i]
  cache = columns
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `awk` could be the following

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){A[i] = $i}} END {for(i in A){str = str" "A[i];} print str}' test.dat
```

This outputs

```
5 3.0 3 4.0 2 2.0 1 3.0
```

The way it works, `awk` reads every line and I tell it to store each `nth` column into its respective place in an array `A`. If there is no number in the column the previous one is not overwritten and therefore at the end of the file the array `A` should contain every last number from each column. Then we just print this array

Note you said the desired output is

```
5 3.0   3 4.0  1 2.0  1 3.0
```

But from your input the fifth and/or seventh numbers `1` and `1` respectively do not make sense. Is the last `2` on the second line to be considered a number in the fifth or seventh column?